# How to close Mongoose connection after Nuxt generate is done?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm currently using my own serverMiddleware with a Mongoose database connection as an API endpoint for my statically generated Nuxt app. My `nuxt.config.js` looks like this:

```js
import { connection } from "mongoose"

export default {
  target: "static",

  ssr: true,

  generate: {
    async done () {
      await connection.close()
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

When I run `nuxt generate` I get the following message at the end of the console output:

```
⚠ Nuxt Warning
The command 'nuxt generate' finished but did not exit after 5s
This is most likely not caused by a bug in Nuxt
Make sure to cleanup all timers and listeners you or your plugins/modules start.
Nuxt will now force exit

DeprecationWarning: Starting with Nuxt version 3 this will be a fatal error
```

I don't much about this `done` method I'm using since I haven't found any official documentation about it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

add `serverMiddleware` in `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  target: "static",

  ssr: true,

  serverMiddleware: [
     '~/api/app.js'
  ]

  // ...
}
```

and add `app.js`
in your project location

> ~/yourLocation/api/app.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/yourDB', { 
  useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true
})

module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

I want it to work for you, too